# Signals and sleep not working properly

Tags: c, signals, sleep

i have an assignment to make, for university, it is almost done, most thing working, there is just one aspect that is not working and i'm not quite sure how to fix it.. 
The objetivo is to make the problem wait for 2 ctrl+C and close.. But if he catch a first ctrl+C and pass more then 3 seconds the program must forget about it and wait again for another 2 ctrl+C. This is how i'm doing it:

```
/*Problem 2. Write a program that sleeps forever until the user interrupts it twice with a Ctrl-C, and
then exits. Once the first interrupt is received, tell the user: “Interrupt again to exit.”. The first
interrupt should be forgotten 3 seconds after it has occurred. Additionally, the program should block
the SIGQUIT signal, and ignore the SIGTSTP signal. The program should start by printing “Interrupt
twice with Ctrl-C to quit.” on the screen.*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

//handler to catch the first ctrl_c and ask user to do it another time(no reference to time limit)
void ctrl_c(int sig){
    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);  
    printf("\nInterrupt again to exit.\n");
}

//handler for second ctrl_c. If called, program will end
void second_catch(int sig){
   if(sig == SIGINT){
       printf("\n");
       exit(0);
   }
}

//handler to always ignore ctrl_z
void ctrl_z(int sig){
   signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
}

int main(){
    //blocking SIQUIT (Ctrl+\) using series of command to change the mask value of SIGQUIT
    sigset_t sg;
    sigemptyset (&sg);
    sigaddset(&sg, SIGQUIT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sg, NULL);

    //installing handler to ignore SIGTSTP (Ctrl+Z)
    signal(SIGTSTP, ctrl_z);

    //two part SIGINT handling
    printf("\nInterrupt twice with Ctrl+C to quit.\n");
    signal(SIGINT, ctrl_c); //first handler install

    do{ //cycle for second hanler install and 3 second timer
        if(sleep(3) == 0){
           main(); //if second_catch handler is not called within 3 seconds,       program will restart
        }
        else {
           signal(SIGINT, second_catch); //upon call, program will end
        }   
    }while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

What's happening is that it keeps reseting after 3 seconds, in a loop.. But i want to reset only 1 time after i click ctrl+c and 3 seconds passed..
What must i change?

Comment: Don't sleep, use `clock()` to find out elapsed time since last Ctrl-C event. You only need one event handler. Then your program should work properly if, say, you press Ctrl-C three times with the intervals 5 seconds, 1 second. The program does not have to "forget" anything, but remember the time stamp of the last event.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No, `clock()` is not [async-signal safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), and it measures CPU time taken, not wall clock time. Use [`time()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) instead. Better yet, use `sigaction()` instead of `signal()`, and [`clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&tspec)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) instead of `time()` for nanosecond precision.

Comment: @NominalAnimal the question does not distinguish.

Comment: Why exactly do you feel the need to *recurse* into `main()`?

Comment: @EOF, i do that so after 3 seconds passed i can restart the program and wait again for 2 ctrl+c. So he can "forget" the first one

Comment: That's no use if the program was busy doing something interesting.

Comment: @CésarPereira: Calling `main()` in the program does *not* restart the program.

Comment: @EOF, so how can i do it?

Comment: @NominalAnimal `clock_gettime` is a non-standard function.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Huh? It's perfectly standard POSIX.1 function.

Comment: @CésarPereira: There is no portable way for a program to restart itself. If you're on POSIX, and the program is in the `PATH`, and the name of the program conforms to convention, you can `execvp(argv[0], argv);`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal well, if you are on a unix-like system. It is a system function. However `clock` on my system is actually nonstandard: it measures wall time not net time.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The only real standard that defines functions like `sigprocmask()` is IEEE Std 1003.1, AKA POSIX.1. C89/C90/C99/C11 has none of these. So, if it is used, then POSIX.1 has to be the governing standard. Stop waffling, please.

Comment: @NominalAnimal "C89/C90/C99/C11 has none of these". That's why I said non-standard.

Comment: @WeatherVane: POSIX.1 is just as valid a programming standard as C89/C99/C11 is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is unlikely to lead to a working program.

First, use a signal handler that only sets a global variable (of `volatile sig_atomic_t` type) whenever a `SIGINT` signal is caught. Do not try to print anything from the signal handler, as standard I/O is not async-signal safe.

Second, use [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to install the signal handler. Use zero flags. In other words, do NOT use `SA_RESTART` flag when installing the handler. This way, when a signal is delivered to your handler, it will interrupt most syscalls (including sleeps). (The functions will return -1 with `errno == EINTR`.)

This way, after your `main()` has installed the signal handler, you can have it print the instruction, and enter into a loop.

In the loop, clear the interrupt flag, and sleep for a few seconds. It does not matter how long. If the interrupt flag is not set after the sleep completes, `continue` (at the beginning of the loop).

Otherwise, you know that the user has pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. So, clear the interrupt flag, and sleep for another three seconds. If the flag is set after the sleep completes, you know the user supplied another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and you can break out of the loop. Otherwise, you just continue the loop again.

---

Technically, there is a race condition here, as the user might press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice in a row, rapidly enough so that the `main()` only sees one.

Unfortunately, increments (`flag++`) are not atomic; the compiler or the hardware may actually do `temp = flag; temp = temp + 1; flag = temp;` and the signal may be delivered just before the third step, leading to the signal handler and `main()` seeing different values of `flag`.

One way around that is to use C11 atomics (if the architecture and C library provides them, in `<stdatomic.h>`, with macro `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE` defined): `volatile atomic_int flag;` for the flag, `__atomic_add_fetch(&flag, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` to increment it, and `__atomic_sub_fetch(&flag, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` to decrement it.

Another way would be to use a [POSIX semaphore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html). The signal handler can increment it (using [`sem_post()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html)) safely. In `main()`, you can use [`sem_timedwait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) to wait for the signal for a limited time, and `sem_trywait()` to decrement it.

A third way would be to use [`sigtimedwait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigtimedwait.2.html) to catch the signal in `main()` with a timeout, without any signal handlers. This last one is, I believe, the most robust and simple to implement, so that's what I'd use in a real application.

---

It turns out that there is another way to achieve this, one that responds to two consecutive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> presses within three seconds, without leaving any nasty corner cases.

This is NOT exactly what was asked of OP, and as such is not a valid answer to their exercise, but this would be a good approach otherwise.

The idea is to use [`alarm()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) and a `SIGALRM` handler, and two `sig_atomic_t` flags: one that counts the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keypresses, and one that flags the case when there have been two in a three-second period.

Unfortunately, `sleep()` cannot be used in this case -- you have to use [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) instead --, as `sleep()`, `alarm()`, and `SIGALRM` signal handling may interfere with each other.

Essentially, we use

```
#define INTR_SECONDS 3

static volatile sig_atomic_t  done = 0;
static volatile sig_atomic_t  interrupted = 0;

static void handle_sigalrm(int signum)
{
    if (interrupted > 1)
        done = 1;
    interrupted = 0;
}

static void handle_sigint(int signum)
{
    interrupted++;
    if (interrupted > 1) {
        done = 1;
        alarm(1);
    } else
        alarm(INTR_SECONDS);
}
```

`handle_sigalrm()` is installed as the `SIGALRM` handler, with `SIGINT` in its signal mask; `handle_sigint()` is installed as the `SIGINT` handler, with `SIGALRM` in its signal mask. This way the two signal handlers block each other, and won't be interrupted by each other.

When a first `SIGINT` is received, the alarm is primed. If this is the second (or third etc.) `SIGINT` without an intervening `SIGALRM`, we also set the done flag, and prime the alarm to occur in one second, to ensure we catch the state change in at most one second.

When a `SIGALRM` is received, the interrupt count is zeroed. If it was two or more, the done flag is also set.

In `main()`, we only check `done` and `interrupted`, never modify them. This avoids the corner cases I was worried about.

In the worst case, there is one second delay to quitting, if the second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is delivered after we check, but just before we sleep. The `alarm(1)` in `handle_sigint()` is for just that case.

The loop in `main` is then just

```
while (!done) {

    while (!done && !interrupted)
        nanosleep(&naptime, NULL);

    if (done)
        break;

    printf("Ctrl+C again to quit!\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    while (interrupted == 1 && !done)
        nanosleep(&naptime, NULL);
}
```

The first inner loop only sleeps when it has been over three seconds since the last `SIGINT` (or we never received one). It will be interrupted by both `SIGINT` and `SIGALRM`, so the duration does not matter.

The `if (done) break;` case just avoids printing anything if the user had lightning hands and typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice really fast.

The second inner loop only sleep when we are waiting for a second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. It too will be interrupted by both signals, so the duration here does not matter either. Note, however, that we do wish to check `interrupted` first, to ensure we catch all changes reliably. (If we checked `done` first, we might be interrupted before we check `interrupted`, and it is possible, in theory, that `done` changes to nonzero and `interrupt` to zero and then to 1 in the mean time. But, if we check `interrupted` first, and it is 1, any additional interrupts will just set `done`, which we'll catch. So, `interrupted == 1 && done == 0` is the correct check in the correct order here.)

As noted above, the duration specified for `nanosleep()` does not actually matter, as it will be interrupted by the signal delivery anyway. Something like ten seconds should be fine,

```
struct timespec naptime = { .tv_sec = 10, .tv_nsec = 0L };
```

If the lecturer had recommended POSIX.1 functions (`sigaction()`, `nanosleep()`), this would have been surprisingly interesting exercise.

Comment: How are thread-safe atomics relevant for single-threaded asynchronous code?

Comment: @EOF:  Because `++flag` and `--flag` are not atomic, and may be interrupted by the signal after `temp = flag; temp = temp + 1;` but before `flag = temp`, leading to incorrect value of `flag`. The user may type Ctrl+C rapidly twice in a row. To handle that, "setting the flag" means the signal handler increments it, and "clearing it" (after the first one, but before the end of the three-second grace period) means decrementing it. It's only zeroed at the start of each loop iteration. I shall explain it better, with a better workaround.

Comment: Well, unfortunately `sig_atomic_t` is not among the `_Atomic` types suitable for the `atomic_fetch_op()` functions. I suggest rethinking your approach, and clarifying what you think the program should actually do.

Comment: Unfortunately, `atomic_int` is not guaranteed to be lock-free. If `!atomic_is_lock_free(&flag)`, the program will exhibit undefined behavior for modifying an object that is not lock-free atomic or of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` in a signal handler.

Comment: @EOF: Ah yes, we need `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE` defined as well. (It is obvious, I guess, how much I actually rely on the atomic/sync built-ins provided by GCC, Pathscale, Portland Group, and Intel CC compilers in real life, rather than the written text of the standards. Honestly, I was quite a bit disappointed in C11.)

Comment: I'd have just blocked the relevant signal while modifying the flag in non-signal context, and unblocked afterwards, which would eliminate the race condition without resorting to C11 atomics (as much as I love them).

Comment: @EOF: Right; that avoids the atomics issue. Even with that, there is a small corner case left: if the interrupt occurs just before the sleep. It's not too bad, as the program only sleeps for the extra three seconds before realizing there was a second Ctrl+C, but that's why I think the `sigtimedwait()` approach in general is superior.

Comment: I've just read your last edit, very interesting approach. I was wondering why you use `alarm(1)` in the `SIGINT` handler though, why not just `raise(SIGALRM)` instead?

Comment: @EOF: There is always a small time window between testing the flags, and `nanosleep()`. The example uses `alarm(1)` to span that window: in the unlikely case that a signal is delivered after the tests but before the `nanosleep()`, `alarm(1)` interrupts the sleep. If we used `raise()` instead, it would probably be handled before the sleep too, and not interrupt the sleep.

Comment: I see, though *technically* that doesn't remove the race, it only makes it (vastly) less likely to occur in practice. I'd prefer the `sigtimedwait()` though.

Comment: @EOF: In the above code, no -- but the case where the race could occur (system so overloaded that the code at hand does not get any CPU in a full second) standard POSIX signal delivery gets fracked up anyway. (Such a two-signal approach for interrupting the process is extremely poor if you consider an overloaded system.)

Comment: @EOF: In cases where I do use (realtime) signals to interrupt syscalls, for that reason I favor the pattern where the signal is repeated at close intervals (say, every few milliseconds) after the original delay, until disarmed, to actually close the race. That way, even in the unlikely case where a signal is delivered after the checks but before the sleep or blocking syscall, we interrupt it "promptly". It is not optimal, but it gives us a guarantee that a sleep/blocking syscall will be interrupted, *eventually*.